# composer updateの意味

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer

「composer updateとは何か」を簡単にでいいので理解したく投稿致しました。

今まで作業していたディレクトリで突然下記のエラーが発生しました。
`Laravel Class mailer does not exist`

調べたところ [Laravel Class mailer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503654/laravel-class-mailer-does-not-exist) にて同じ悩みの方を発見し、`composer update`で無事解決。
確かに数日updateをさぼっておりました。しかし、updateはしていなくても何かのデータを消したり、劣化版に変えたわけでもないのになぜこういった状況が起きるのでしょうか？

参考になるHPや知っておいたほうが良い概念等ございましたら、ご教授下さい。